# Constructor not defined: [cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem].<Constructor> for parameterized constructor

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

My class

```
global with sharing class cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem{
    public String sfid { get; set; }
    public String productId { get; set; }
    public String productName { get; set; }
    public String productSKU { get; set; }
    public String prodSalesMethod { get; set; }
    public String unitOfMeasureQuantity { get; set; }
    public Integer quantityPerUnit{get;set;}
    public string inventory{get;set;}
    public Integer quantity { get; set; }
    public Integer quantityInCart { get; set; }
    public Date productEndDate{get;set;}
    public Boolean bolQty{get;set;}
    public Boolean productblocked{get;set;}
    public cc_ccr_bean_MediaWrapper mediaWrapper { get; set; }
    public String unitOfMeasure{ get; set; }
    public String tradeMark{ get; set; }
    public string userLocale{get;set;}
    public string brand{get;set;}
    public string category{get;set;}


    /* Default constructor for cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem */
    public cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem() {}

    /* Parametreized constructor for cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem */
    public cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem(   String productId,
                                    String productNameP,
                                    String productSKUP,
                                    String unitOfMeasureQuantityP,
                                    Integer quantityPerUnit,
                                    string inventory,
                                    Integer quantityP,
                                    Integer quantityInCartP,
                                    cc_ccr_bean_MediaWrapper mediaWrapper, String unitOfMeasure,
                                    String tradeMark, Date productEndDate, Boolean bolQty,string userLocale,Boolean productblocked) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productNameP;
        this.productSKU = productSKUP;
        this.unitOfMeasureQuantity = unitOfMeasureQuantityP;
        this.quantityPerUnit = quantityPerUnit;
        this.inventory = inventory;
        this.quantity = quantityP;
        this.quantityInCart = quantityInCartP;
        this.mediaWrapper = mediaWrapper;
        this.tradeMark= tradeMark;
        this.unitOfMeasure= unitOfMeasure;
        this.productEndDate = productEndDate;
        this.bolQty = bolQty;
        this.userLocale =userLocale;
        this.productblocked = productblocked;



    }
```

Test Class

```
static testmethod void testcc_ccr_bean_OrderItem1()
{ 
    Products__c p = AP101_TestDatFactory_TEST.createProducts('Ram', 'name', 'pending');
    String stringDate = '2016-10-13 00:00:00';
    Datetime myDate = datetime.valueOf(stringDate);
    cc_ccr_bean_MediaWrapper mw= new cc_ccr_bean_MediaWrapper();
    String productNameP='fruit';
    String productSKUP='123';
    String unitOfMeasureQuantityP='kgs';
    Integer quantityPerUnit=10;
    string inventory='23';
    Integer quantityP=10;
    Integer quantityInCartP=15;                                 
    String unitOfMeasure='k';
    String tradeMark='AB';                                         
    Boolean bolQty=true;
    string userLocale='CAN';
    Boolean productblocked=false;
    cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem controller= new cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem(p.Id,'fruit','123','kgs',10, '23', 10, 15, mw, 'k','AB',myDate, true, 'CAN',false);
}
```

Comment: Needed more explanation one your question

Comment: to many parameter in constructor.  Use Builder [pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

```
            Datetime myDate = datetime.valueOf(stringDate);
```

This is a DateTime here, but...

```
String tradeMark, Date productEndDate, Boolean bolQty,string userLocale,Boolean productblocked) {
```

Is a Date here.

Change the DateTime to a Date, or use the DateTime.date method:

```
cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem controller= new cc_ccr_bean_OrderItem(p.Id,

      'fruit',
      '123',
     'kgs',
    10,
     '23',
    10,
    15,
    mw, 'k',
    'AB', myDate.date(), true, 'CAN',false);
```